# login?error after logging and no message Spring

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have following problem
I have simple register and logging to the site with Spring Security after successful registration ( user added to the db i added screen below)

[image]

When i want to log in i just go in url:

> http://localhost:8080/login?error

And nothing else like error i don`t know what is wrong the username and password is correct

This is my view login.html

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/login}" id="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Nazwa użytkownika: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Hasło: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj się" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

and SecurityConfig

```
package my.taco.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/design","/orders").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/","/**").access("permitAll")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/design",true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");


    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web){
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/h2/**");
    }

}
```

I need to add something like logging controller or what? i`m newbie in Spring
Thank you for help everyone.

Added implements UserDetailsService in reply to the comment

```
package my.taco.services;

import my.taco.data.UserRepository;
import my.taco.models.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserRepositoryUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Autowired
    public UserRepositoryUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepo){
        this.userRepo=userRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException{
        User user=userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        if(user!=null){
            return user;
        }
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Użytkwonik "+username+ " nie został znaleziony");
    }
}
```

Added User class

```
package my.taco.models;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;


@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE,force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final String fullname;
    private final String street;
    private final String city;
    private final String state;
    private final String zip;
    private final String phoneNumber;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(){
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired(){
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked(){
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired(){
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didnt send the CSRF token. Add this token to your login page.

Comment: I add token also when i disable csrf still the same

Answer (score 0):

Hello, in this case I would recommend you to implement UserDetailsService:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final LoginService loginService;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(LoginService loginService) {
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LoginDto user = loginService.findUserByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " not found");
        }

        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole())));
    }
}
```

You should debug your code in the `loadUserByUsername` method, which will give you a clear understanding of your problem: the required username does not come, there is no user in the database or something else. Keep in mind, the `User` class from the package `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails`. Have a nice day

Comment: It is not necessary to mix the Entity and UserDetails, better to divide it into two different classes, so what about debug?

Comment: Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=her_7pa0vrg&ab_channel=Amigoscode), it will definitely give you an understanding of what is wrong with code